# SwiftUI OnDelete crashes using indices and bindings

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-foreach

I'm building an app where you have cards for each study item that is stored in an array and what I wanted to do was to allow the user to swipe left on a study item and allow them to delete the card.

Each card has two bindings to allow user to edit two textFields, so I have to use indices on the ForEach to specify the textField that is being edited, because when I don't use indices and have the foreach parameter as a binding and iterate through each item, when the user edits a specify textField, he can only type in one letter and it skips to the next textField.

In this case, present below, I am able to swipe left on each card("Section") and delete it when it's empty but when I start typing on individual textFields with different texts and delete it, it crashes.

Any help will be appreciated!

**Here is the foreach loop that is in a subview of another view**

```
@ObservedObject var currentStudySet: HomeViewModel

ForEach(currentStudySet.studySet.studyItem.indices, id: \.self) { index in
    Section {
        VStack {
            TextField("Title", text: $currentStudySet.studySet.studyItem[index].itemTitle)
            .padding(5)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .background(backgroundColor)
            .cornerRadius(10)

            TextField("Description", text: $currentStudySet.studySet.studyItem[index].itemDescription)
            .padding(5)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .background(backgroundColor)
            .cornerRadius(10)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}
.onDelete(perform: { (item) in
    currentStudySet.studySet.studyItem.remove(atOffsets: item)
})
```

**The view model has studySet but I won't put it for legibility purposes but here is the StudyModel that is "studySet"**

```
struct StudyModel: Hashable{
    var title: String = ""
    var days = ["One day", "Two days", "Three days", "Four days", "Five days", "Six days", "Seven days"]
    var studyGoals = "One day"
    var studyItem: [StudyItemModel] = []
}
```

**Here is the studyItemModel which is the studyItem array in StudyModel**

```
struct StudyItemModel: Hashable{
    var itemTitle: String = ""
    var itemDescription: String = ""
}
```

Comment: Indicies is considered unsafe in SwiftUI you can watch Demystify SwiftUI for more info and alternatives

Comment: For completeness, [Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thank you for linking the video. It was very helpful, in understanding identities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid using the index by doing the model conforms to `Identifiable`, this is the way the `ForEach` is meant to be use in SwiftUI atleast

```
import Foundation
                import SwiftUI

                struct fortest: View {
                    
                    @ObservedObject var currentStudySet: HomeViewModel = HomeViewModel()
                    
                    var body: some View {
                        
                        List {
                            ForEach($currentStudySet.studySet.studyItem) { $studyItem in
                                Section {
                                    VStack {
                                        TextField("Title", text: $studyItem.itemTitle)
                                            .padding(5)
                                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                            .background(Color.gray)
                                            .cornerRadius(10)
                                        
                                        TextField("Description", text: $studyItem.itemDescription)
                                            .padding(5)
                                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                            .background(Color.gray)
                                            .cornerRadius(10)
                                    }
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                }
                            }
                            .onDelete(perform: { (item) in
                                currentStudySet.studySet.studyItem.remove(atOffsets: item)
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }

                class HomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
                    @Published var studySet: StudyModel = StudyModel()
                }

                struct StudyModel: Hashable{
                    var title: String = ""
                    var days = ["One day", "Two days", "Three days", "Four days", "Five days", "Six days", "Seven days"]
                    var studyGoals = "One day"
                    var studyItem: [StudyItemModel] = [StudyItemModel(itemTitle: "test 1", itemDescription: "hello"), StudyItemModel(itemTitle: "test 2", itemDescription: "hello"), StudyItemModel(itemTitle: "test 3", itemDescription: "hello")]
                }

                struct StudyItemModel: Hashable, Identifiable{
                    let id = UUID()
                    var itemTitle: String = ""
                    var itemDescription: String = ""
                }
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I had a feeling, it had something to do with the id because when I changed other than .self, it semi-worked.